# Extract a table from call_history.db using C++ and sqlite

Tags: iphone, c++, sqlite

I'm developing an iphone app that retrieves the call log information and store it with the number of missed,incoming and received calls over that time. Here, since the call log is a .db file, i have to first access the call log details and extract it using C++ and sqlite.

Can anyone suggest me how to extract the table named "call" from call_history.db database file and store it in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is allowed by Apple to access the call history database... If it is, which I seriously doubt, then you should be able to open it using sqlite3. There are plenty of tutorials available online how to do this but again, I think, if it is even possible, that your app will be rejected for this...

Comment: to elaborate on the first part: [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) `2.6. Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected`

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to try, the `call_history.db` file is probably a sqlite3 database.
Have a look [at the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) to see how to access it from your code. If you want to analyze the contents first to find out the schema, just use the command line application `sqlite3`.